# Small Basic: What did I do wrong?

Tags: smallbasic

Hello I just started using small basic and there is a simple program that I compiled but something is wrong.

```
 Total = ((Loan*Loanp/100)+Expense)-Salary
TextWindow.WriteLine("Your Loan: ")
Loan = TextWindow.ReadNumber() 
TextWindow.WriteLine ("Your Loan %: ")
TextWindow.ReadNumber(Loanp)
TextWindow.WriteLine ("Your Expense: ")
Expense = TextWindow.ReadNumber()
TextWindow.WriteLine ("Your Salary: ")
Salary = TextWindow.ReadNumber()
If (Loan*Loanp/100)+Expense > Salary Then
  TextWindow.WriteLine ("Error : You are FOREVER in loan")
Else
  TextWindow.WriteLine ("You savings are "+Total)

EndIf
```

the answer is always zero.
when I try to set a number to "Total" then It works
Eg.

```
Total = 100*3/100+50
TextWindow.WriteLine("Your Loan: ")
Loan = TextWindow.ReadNumber() 
TextWindow.WriteLine ("Your Loan %: ")
TextWindow.ReadNumber(Loanp)
TextWindow.WriteLine ("Your Expense: ")
Expense = TextWindow.ReadNumber()
TextWindow.WriteLine ("Your Salary: ")
Salary = TextWindow.ReadNumber()
If (Loan*Loanp/100)+Expense > Salary Then
  TextWindow.WriteLine ("Error : You are FOREVER in loan")
Else
  TextWindow.WriteLine ("You savings are "+Total)
EndIf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the values of 'Loan', 'Loanp', `Salary` and `Expense` (to compute `Total`) before you have read them in!  You need to move the line that computes `Total` to somewhere after the line where you read in the value, e.g., after `Salary = TextWindow.ReadNumber()`.